# Wine + Cygwin garbles argv

Tags: cygwin, mingw, wine, msys

I'm trying to compile a program ([sbcl](http://sbcl.org) to be precise) under Wine + MinGW/Cygwin environment. I've fixed plethora of different quirks, but now I'm stuck on the fact that this environment breaks command line arguments in weird way. The problem is that build shellscript contains the lines

```sh
./src/runtime/sbcl --core output/cold-sbcl.core \
 --lose-on-corruption $SBCL_MAKE_TARGET_2_OPTIONS --no-sysinit --no-userinit \
 --eval '(sb-fasl::!warm-load "src/cold/warm.lisp")' --quit
```

...but within the running `sbcl` process the last command line argument appears as `(sb-fasl;!warm-load "src/cold/warm.lisp")`, which is, of course, syntactically incorrect and the build fails.

I've performed some tests with different versions of wine (I've tried versions 6.0, 6.12 and 6.15) and win32 bash (I've tried a plenty of those, including [busybox for windows](https://frippery.org/busybox), currently stuck with the one from old MSYS-20111123.zip from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/) since it does not exhibit [FAST_CWD bug](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/682) that is currently not fixed). It appears that every time the command line contains both double colon and forward slash, some part of the environment changes double colon to semicolon. I'm not sure where to look for that behaviour to circumvent it - is that shell escaping, or `exec` syscall behaviour? Could it be that this behaviour is hardcoded into `exec` function in `msvcrt.dll`?

Comment: It tries to adjust a linux-style path list (`:`-separated) to windows style (`;`-separated`). On MSYS2 this is disabled using `MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=*` env variable, but unsure about Cygwin.

Comment: Why are you using Cygwin bash to begin with? I've been successfully using native bash for this purpose. Are you compiling with Cygwin OR with regular MinGW?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Unfortunately `MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL` nor `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL`  hasn't helped, but I'll dig more in that direction.

Comment: I've started with just MinGW, but then added Cygwin to the mix exactly because the build needs a bunch of standard unix utilities (bash, expr, uname, that kind of thing). The native bash wouldn't do, since the build is not crosscompilation-aware and I have to run it fully under Wine.

Comment: [Here's how I solved this issue](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2), maybe it can serve as an inspiration. Or maybe you can use my setup directly. I'm using native bash, native unix utilities, `binfmt_misc` to transparently run wine apps (so you can lie to build systems that you're not cross-compiling), libraries and headers from MSYS2, and either MSYS2 GCC under Wine (slow) or native Clang + MSYS2 GCC headers. This works completely without Cygwin, so you don't have to find ancient wine-compatible Cygwin.

Comment: Thank you @HolyBlackCat ! I'll give it a go.